# Classes / Interfaces - TypeError: s is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing my first Typescript/Angular2 application and I'm  having some trouble with classes/interfaces.

This is my interface:

```
export interface Discount {
    codSco: string;
    desSco: string;
}
```

and this is the routine where I try to instantiate an element of type Discount:

```
var Discount;

s.codSco = '44';
s.desSco = '44';
```

And this is the error message that I get:

**TypeError: s is undefined**

I think I have to create a class that inherit from interfaces right?
Can you provide me some guidlines?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

```
export interface Discount {
    codSco: string;
    desSco: string;
}

const s: Discount = {
  codSco: '44',
  desSco: '44'
};
```

Option 2:

```
export class Discount {
    codSco: string;
    desSco: string;
}

const s = new Discount();

s.codSco = '44';
s.desSco = '44';
```

To sum up: you must assign value to the variables you declare. Either via class constructor, or object literals.

Comment: Thanks Amid but... Why I have to use constants ?
I need to generete lot of Discount inside a loop and add them to an array of Discount...

Comment: `const s` is used in place of `let s` (its better to forget about `var s` if you are using typescript) if the variable `s` will not be reassigned later on. It does not mean that properties of `s` cant be changed.